# Dynamically reloading classes in C# (looping through all instances)

Tags: c#, game-engine

I am building a game engine in C#, and my goal is to be able to dynamically edit and reload component classes that are also written in C#. From what I've discovered via a few different examples, it is indeed possible to load an assembly (DLL) into an AppDomain, then unload it and reload an edited/recompiled version it its place. Through my own testing I've found that it works quite well, the only problem left is eliminating all the run-time references to a particular instance of that object so that it can be reloaded and replaced.

Basically, I would like to be able to get a list of all references to a particular object. I am aware that this may be entirely impossible in C#, as it depends heavily on the language storing a list of all objects referencing a particular object. It does not matter if the implementation is incredibly slow, so long as it works properly.

I've pasted some pseudo-code here for what I want to be able to do:
http://nopaste.dk/p3059

I know one way I could do this is to have my own "weak reference" type that I basically use everywhere, and never create direct references to an object. This seems like a bit of a headache, but at least unloading the AppDomain would throw an exception if any true references to the object still existed. Basically this puts the management into my hands, instead of being automatic and enforceable.

If you know a good way to do this, or you think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong, feel free to speak up, and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't checked it out already, you should really take a look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/). It will save you a lot of time rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: [Edit] Seems like they've also built the composition object with component based design in mind... interesting. I'm going to be doing all the editing, testing, and playing on PC, however, the core component architecture needs to compile on XBox under the .NET XNA framework; MEF might not run on XBox :/

Comment: Works in WinPho7 so I'd be surprised if you can't get it working under XBox.

Comment: Awesome! This will certainly be a tool that will forever remain in my toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

WeakReference already exists. It's a decent idea.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404247.aspx

Also, for loading .dll's in a "plug-in" like fashion, check out MEF. It abstracts a lot of the work for you.

http://mef.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you do go down the route of managing this yourself, bear in mind that all references across the AppDomain will be via proxy references and not actually pointing to the instance.  All of your marshalled instances must also derive from MarshalByRefObject in order for the proxies to be generated.

One option you could use is to organize your Game so that almost the entire game is in one AppDomain, with the main AppDomain being a relatively shallow hosting shell.  This minimizes the number of cross-AppDomain calls you make while the game is actually running, which will tend to be slow.  To re-load add-ons, you would then:

- Serialize your game state using something like DataContractSerializer that can maintain references.
- Unload entire Game AppDomain
- Load new Game AppDomain
- Deserialize your game state, which will now resolve to the newly loaded types when reconstructing them.